# anchor tag shows links for previous controller links too codeigniter

Tags: url, view, controller, codeigniter-2

I am beginner to codeigniter and I was creating a simple application to show the pending customers and the admin can active it. But when I linked from view

`echo 'Not activated.<a href="create_ac/activate_customer/'.$v->cust_id.'"> Activate Now ? </a>';`

the link is like `localhost/ci/index.php/create_ac/show_ac_details/create_ac/activate_customer/`

where my customer is shown from the controller `create_ac`'s function `show_ac_details()` and I will handle the customer in controller `create_ac`'s function `activate_customer()`.

Whats wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo 'Not activated.<a href="activate_customer/'.$v->cust_id.'">
Activate Now ? </a>';
```

It's better to use [codeigniter url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).
Then you can use `anchor()` function like this

```
echo anchor("create_ac/activate_customer/" . $v->cust_id, 'Activate Now ?');
```

I am not sure about the $v->cust_id variable. Are you sure, that's getting the correct data. I don't see it in your link.